# Set more specific zoom layer for png export of leaflet map?

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet

I have to create and export multiple maps that zoom to particular areas of my county. The issue I'm having is that zoom level 12 is too far away, and zoom level 13 is too close. Is there a way to set specific boundaries for a png export of a map through code?

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)

northmap<-leaflet()  %>% addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -90.264027, lat  = 38.803011, zoom = 12) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri")

mapshot(northmap, file = "northmap1.png",
        remove_controls = c("homeButton", "zoomControl"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `zoomSnap` and `zoomDelta` in the options of the map which will enable smaller zoom increments. Note, though, that the background tiles only exist at integer zoom levels (0, 1, 2, etc.) and as such the background may look a little blurred at intermediate steps.

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapview)
library(leafem) # for mouseControls to check zoom levels

northmap<-leaflet(options = leafletOptions(zoomSnap = 0.25, zoomDelta = 0.25)) %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = -90.264027, lat  = 38.803011, zoom = 12.75) %>% 
  addProviderTiles("Esri") %>%
  leafem::addMouseCoordinates()

northmap

mapshot(northmap, file = "northmap1.png",
        remove_controls = c("homeButton", "zoomControl"))
```

Note, I added `leafem::addMouseCoordinates()` to enable checking of the zoom loevels.

Comment: Thanks, that allowed me to zoom in and out at .25 in the viewer, but now my issue is the mapshot is still only exporting at full integers. Do you know what to do about that?

Comment: Are you sure? It seemed to me that setting zoom to 12.5 worked when exporting the map

Comment: Yeah, I tested it at multiple intervals by changing the zoom and comparing the output pngs. The right zoom would be 12.25, but anything less than 12.5 exports at 12 zoom. And 12.5 or higher exports at 13 zoom.

Comment: You're right, I was comparing 12 and 12.75 so thought it worked... I am out of ideas sorry.